# AJAX и отображение результата на странице

Tags: php, html, ajax, вывод

**Здравствуйте!**

Нужна помощь, чтобы разобраться в проблеме, писал **ajax** для динамического обновления товаров на своем сайте. Дебажил с помощью **var_dump()**, он мне вернул такой вот результат.

[image: alert() с возвращением результата]

Код элемента HTML приходит как видно, но странице плитка товаров как была так и осталась, ничего не изменилось\заменилось. Я думал, может быть они наложились друг на друга. Прошу помощи с решением данной проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так понимаю у вас php значит в самом верху пропишите

```html
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

а в самом аякс запросе пропишите

```js
dataType:'html'
```

Comment: где именно? 

   $("#sort").click(function () {
        if (modelSelect !== null) {
            $.post("modules/view.php", {
                model: modelSelect,
                memory: memorySelect,
                color: colorSelect,
                state: stateSelect,
                device: deviceSelect,
                filter_macbook_display: sizeSelect,
                filter_serias: seriesSelect

            }, function (data, status) {
                dataType:'html';
            });
        }
        else {
            alert("Модель!");
        }
    });

Comment: $("#sort").click(function () {
if (modelSelect !== null) {
$.post("modules/view.php", 
{
model: modelSelect, 
memory: memorySelect, 
color: colorSelect, 
state: stateSelect, 
dataType:'html',
device: deviceSelect, 
filter_macbook_display: sizeSelect,
filter_serias: seriesSelect}, 
function (data, status) { 
}); 
} 
else { 
alert("Модель!"); 
} });

Comment: ранее ты же не использовал dataType?

Comment: нет, не использовал

Comment: тогда всё должно заработать проверь

Comment: не пашет, почему хз

Comment: можешь пожалуйста в скайпе помочь?

Comment: да пиши свой скайп

Comment: skype: cyberx_hack